# Json to csv conversion in Spring boot

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, csv

I have a csv structure like this

[image]

and I also have one json response

```
    [
 {
  "ID"   : "1",
  "Name" : "abc",
  "Mobile" : "123456"
   },
   {
  "ID"   : "2",
  "Name" : "cde",
  "Mobile" : "123345"
   }
   ]
```

I need the output like this

[image]

Comment: Ok. What is your question?

Comment: How to add  these json values to the corresponding csv file

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to convert directly the JSON then that baeldung solution that you were given is good.

Otherwise, the way i see it and based on the info you're giving, you will need to have a representation of that JSON in a java object that will either represent some kind of request coming from somewhere or data you're getting from your database in order to be written on a csv.

Check out these, might be useful:
https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring-boot/csv-export-example

https://zetcode.com/springboot/csv/